# How to store a list of select component in an array in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, select, frontend

I have a table contains for example 10 rows, each row has a select.

How can i store all selected items from the all 10 rows in an array in state to be like that 
`[{id, value}, {id, value}]`
??

and want to make sure that when i change the selected value from one of the options it changes the previous value in the array.

my current function

```
onSelectGrade(e) {
        const { selectedGrades } = this.state
        let index
        if (e.target.value) {
            let gradeItem = { cid: +e.target.id, id: +e.target.value }
            selectedGrades.push(gradeItem)
        } else {
            index = selectedGrades.indexOf(+e.target.id)
            selectedGrades.splice(index, 1)
        }
        this.setState({ selectedGrades: selectedGrades })
    }
```

and here is the select component it the table's row

```
                              <select
                                defaultValue="Default"
                                id={customer.id.toString()}
                                onChange={this.onSelectGrade}
                                className="browser-default custom-select"
                            >
                                <option disabled value="Default">Choose grade</option>
                                {customer.categoryList &&
                                    customer.categoryList.map(cat =>
                                        <option
                                            key={cat.id}
                                            value={cat.id.toString()}>
                                            {cat.name}
                                        </option>
                                    )}
                            </select>
```

but it doesn't work as i need.. it stores the array like this [{"cid":11,"id":2},{"cid":11,"id":3}]
but i need it like this [{11, 2},{11, 3}]

and when i change an option added before it adds it one more time

and it delays clicks by 1, that means the first choice return empty array> then the second choice return array contains the first choice.. and so on

Please help if you can,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When setting state, especially with array, you need to return *a new array reference* since react does shallow reference equality checks to test if a re-render is necessary.

```
onSelectGrade(e) {
    const { selectedGrades } = this.state
    let newSelectedGrades;
    let index;
    if (e.target.value) {
        let gradeItem = { cid: +e.target.id, id: +e.target.value }
        // copy previous state and spread into new array with new gradeItem
        newSelectedGrades = [...selectedGrades, gradeItem];
    } else {
        index = selectedGrades.indexOf(+e.target.id)
        // filter previous state if index ins't the one to remove
        newSelectedGrades = selectedGrades.filter((grad, i) => i !== index);
    }
    this.setState({ selectedGrades: newSelectedGrades });
}
```

BTW, `{11, 2}` isn't a valid javascript object. But `[11, 2]` is a valid array object. You can tweak your code to store arrays instead of objects.

```
onSelectGrade(e) {
    const { selectedGrades } = this.state
    let newSelectedGrades;
    let index;
    if (e.target.value) {
        let gradeItem = [ +e.target.id, +e.target.value ];
        // copy previous state and spread into new array with new gradeItem
        newSelectedGrades = [...selectedGrades, gradeItem];
    } else {
        // use array::findIndex since not storing a primitive or object
        index = selectedGrades.findIndex(([, id]) => id === +e.target.id)
        // filter previous state if index ins't the one to remove
        newSelectedGrades = selectedGrades.filter((grad, i) => i !== index);
    }
    this.setState({ selectedGrades: newSelectedGrades });
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem still exist.. it delays by 1 and when i change a previous choice it adds a new record without removing the previous record for the same row

Comment: @ShadyHakim What does "delays by 1" mean? Can you share your entire component code? And if possible, provide a working codesandbox?

Comment: delay by one means: when i choice for the first time it returns an empty array, then the second choice return array contains the first choice.. and so on

Comment: i added the component please see the question again

Comment: @ShadyHakim You only added a `select` element, not an entire component's code. Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-mirzakhani-uvc9h?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) close to what you're trying to achieve? Again, if you share more of the component code (and codesandbox), the context use could be a little clearer.

Comment: Ok, i wrote it in sandbox but i don't know if this is the right url or not but here you are,
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-shannon-sewln